# Readers writers using only semaphores - no shared variable between readers

Tags: c, unix, concurrency, synchronization, semaphore

I have, I guess small problem with ***readers writers***[1]. I need to use semaphores for that task and I can't use shared variables between readers.

I have Writer:

```
    sem_t  *write;
    write = sem_open("/write", O_CREAT, 0600, 1);
​
    do{
        sem_wait(write); 
        printf("Critical section in writer\n");
        sem_post(write);
​
    }while(1);
​
    return 0;
}
```

and Reader:

```
​
int main(){
    sem_t *mutex;
    sem_t *write;
    int count=0;
    mutex = sem_open("/mutex", O_CREAT, 0600, 5);
    write = sem_open("/write", O_CREAT, 0600, 1);
​
    do{
        sem_wait(mutex);
        count++;
        if (count==1){
            sem_wait(write);
        }
        sem_post(mutex);
​
        printf("Critical section in readers\n");
​
        sem_wait(mutex);
        count--;
        if(count==0)
            sem_post(write);
        sem_post(mutex); 
​
    }while(1);
```

My teacher told me to use that pattern to solve it:

```
Reader:
 P(Sw)
 P(Sr)
 V(Sw)
 #read
 V(Sr)

Writer:
  P(Sw)
  for i in 1..N: P(Sr)
  # writing
  for i in 1..N: V(Sr)
  V(Sw)
```

Can someone help me understand why can't I use variable `count` as I was told it is shared between readers, help me understand the idea provided by the teacher and how to implement it. Thanks!

[1] Readers-writers problem: room has a capacity of n readers, readers come to the room, occupy a space there and leave after some time. If the room is empty, writer can get inside, but only one writer can be in the room at the same time. Task: provide implementation of 2 programs implementing readers writers problem so that it is possible to dynamically start new processes while complying with the restrictions

Comment: "Can someone help me understand why can't I use variable `count` as I was told it is shared between readers" - You cannot use shared variables, because it is **constraint** for your task. We don't know why your task have this constraint, ask you teacher instead. "help me understand the idea provided by the teacher and how to implement it." - In the pattern `P` means `sem_wait`, `V` means `sem_post`. You just  need to write the code. What is unclear in that?